# Initialization of data members of a class in c++

Tags: c++, constructor

For a class in c++,we can provide a default constructor as well as any no of parameterized constructors.If we use a constructor initializer list in each of parameterized constructor,then isnt it like we are **initializing** a member more than one time?Is the concept valid?(I thought we can initialize only once).
Also by this logic,if we have a constant data member or a reference,and if I want to initialize the constant with a value provided by user,how can I do it?I found a code snippet in c++ primer which looks like

```
  class constref
   {
    public:
        constref(int ii):i(ii),ci(ii),ri(i)
        {
        }
    private:
        int i;
        const int ci;
        int &ri;
}
```

Isnt the above code wrong.because since we have provided a constructor with parameters,we need to define a default constructor.So the constant and the reference are initialized two times which is an error.How can I make it work?
Thanks

But can you please tell what is happening in this code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class dummy
{
    int a;
public:
      dummy():a(0)
      {
      }
      dummy(int i):a(i)
      {
      }
      void output()
      {
        cout<<a<<endl;
      }
   };
   int main()
   {
    dummy d;
    d=dummy(4);
    d=dummy(3);
    d.output();
    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiple constructors provide multiple ways of initializing an object and its members. When an object is created **one** of the constructors is used, so there is only one initialization. The constructor is selected in accordance with the arguments given when the object is created.

From the example, `constref c(3);` uses the constructor to create the object `c`, passing the value 3 to the constructor. The same thing would happen if the class also defined a default constructor. The presence of a default constructor wouldn't affect the creation of `c` because the default constructor takes no arguments, so can't be called with 3 as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

First , it is not necessary to provide default constructor But if you will not provide it , you can not create objects like `constref c1;` or you can't even create array of object like `constref c1[10]` .The only way you can create object of class constref is by provide **integer argument** to the constructor i.e. `constref c1(10);` .

Second ,constant and reference are not initialize twice in your code .They are initialized only once i.e. interget "i: is initialized with "ii",constant int "ci"is initialized by "ii" again ,similarly with "ri" .

Please note constant data members and reference must be initialization list else it will be flagged by the compiler .

Also , the order in which data members are initialized is totally dependent on  the way they are declared in the class **(not on the way they appear in initialization list)** .
Consider below two different scenarios: 
**Scenario1:**

```
class constref
{
    public:
        constref(int ii):i(ii),ci(ii),ri(i)
        {
        }
    private:
        int i;
        const int ci;
        int &ri;
}
```

here i will be initialized first followed by ci and ri .

**scenario2:**

```
class constref
{
    public:
        constref(int ii):i(ii),ci(ii),ri(i)
        {
        }
    private:
        const int ci;
        int i;
        int &ri;
}
```

Here ci will be initialized first , followed by i , ri .

Answer (score 1):

There is no conflict: An initializer list can BOTH be used with either an empty `{ }` body, OR with a constructor body with statements.

The initializer list will just initialize the members to specific values at the **beginning** of the constructor.

Even if a constructor has an initializer list, you are **still** free to do other work in the body of the constructor.

This:

```
Point(int i = 0, int j = 0):x(i), y(j) {}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
Point(int i = 0, int j = 0) {
        x = i;
        y = j;
    }
```

You would only have different constructor methods if different numbers of variables were passed into the constructor to initialize the class.  Any constructor with arguments can take an initializer list.

---

A default constructor is a constructor that doesn't take any arguments.

You only need to define a default constructor in the case where
an object of the class needs to be instantiated without any arguments.

References:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor